# how to access multiple images from server i have used glide library but i take much time 2 load images in gridview

Tags: android, image, grid, android-viewpager

how to access images from the server and by Url in android
implement like instagram application my confusion is how to show thumbnails in grid view.after clicking on thumbnail show full images using view pager swap images.

I had implement but a problem is images loading taken 2 much times loading in Grandview and after click on image show image in view page with taken 2 much times.

I just thought for it requires fast net speed in my project maximum 700 images.

please anyone know about please share a thought.

Comment: Are there thumbnails/preview images available from the server?

Comment: no sir i just uploaded single image(480*800) for each module not with different size...in glide resize image

Answer (score 0):

While calling Glide.load() set resize options. My app is using a hell lot of images. I am using fresco and it works like charm.